# Please help Highcharts - Windrose graph display bars from top to center

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts windrose graph for one website.

I want to display bar from top to center, not from center to top. How can I do this?

See this illustration image:
[image: Windrose desired result]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `yAxis.reversed` option. Setting it to `true` will make your bars start from the outer edge, when having a polar column graph ("windrose"). Example code:

```
yAxis: {
    reversed: true
}
```

As seen in [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EwA65/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `startAngle / endAngle` like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/4UXva/